# how to split a layer into multiple layers in random formats

Tags: layers, shapes, photo-editing, illustration, selections

I need some software that "breaks" an image into multiple layers without needing to do selection.
Krita has something similar, but the division is done by colors and I want something random. I could do it manually but I need almost 1000 layers it would take almost 1 hour doing. Look like this:

[image]

Comment: "Random" can, by definition, mean many different things. Very jagged shapes, rounded shapes, rectangles, very thin and long shapes. Can you be more specific? What do you need this for? Some kind of jigsaw perhaps?

Comment: There are "jigsaw" scripts out there... which split up an image.. but, of course, you get "jigsaw" shapes.

Comment: Specifically triangles or pentagon. Like a jigsaw, enabling layers to be visible to make a timelapse video @Wolff